# Insert XML file into postgresql table using python

Tags: python, xml, database, postgresql, xml-parsing

I have large XML file which I should insert it to Postgresql table and show them in table by using python. I have tried but I cannot do it properly and searched more documentation but there is nothing about xml files inserting. Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

'''

```
<clearing xmlns="http://bpc.ru/sv/SVXP/clearing">
    <file_id>2109240000000099</file_id>
    <file_type>FLTP1710</file_type>
    <start_date>2021-09-01</start_date>
    <end_date>2021-09-24</end_date>
    <inst_id>1001</inst_id>
    <file_date>2021-09-24</file_date>
    <operation>
        <oper_id>2109020000002175</oper_id>
        <oper_type>OPTP0026</oper_type>
        <msg_type>MSGTAUTH</msg_type>
        <sttl_type>STTT0100</sttl_type>
        <oper_date>2021-09-02T16:44:20</oper_date>
        <host_date>2021-09-02T16:44:20</host_date>
        <oper_amount>
            <amount_value>10000</amount_value>
            <currency>840</currency>
        </oper_amount>
        <oper_request_amount>
            <amount_value>10000</amount_value>
            <currency>840</currency>
        </oper_request_amount>
```

'''

Comment: what is the problem? the xml is just a string - isnt it?

Comment: What did you try ? What's the error ?

Comment: @balderman I am new in programming and I cannot solve this and I have searched how to create or insert xml to table but all of them is small files like they are writing like this:   postgres=# insert into CRICKETERS (
   First_Name, Last_Name, Age, Place_Of_Birth, Country) 
   values('Shikhar', 'Dhawan', 33, 'Delhi', 'India');
INSERT 0 1
postgres=#    but I have more tags to show that's why I am looking for proper code for inserting the data to file